# Plot spatial coordinates with labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, spatial

I am quite new in R. I have number of coordinates and I want to plot them in a proper way in R which also presents labels. Moreover, axises should present the lat and long. I have tries ggplot but I cannot fit the data to the code.

```
   id      lon      lat
1   2 7.173500 45.86880
2   3 7.172540 45.86887
3   4 7.171636 45.86924
4   5 7.180180 45.87158
5   6 7.178070 45.87014
6   7 7.177229 45.86923
7   8 7.175240 45.86808
8   9 7.181409 45.87177
9  10 7.179299 45.87020
10 11 7.178359 45.87070
11 12 7.175189 45.86974
12 13 7.179379 45.87081
13 14 7.175509 45.86932
14 15 7.176839 45.86939
15 17 7.180990 45.87262
16 18 7.180150 45.87248
17 19 7.181220 45.87355
18 20 7.174910 45.86922
19 25 7.154970 45.87058
20 28 7.153399 45.86954
21 29 7.152649 45.86992
22 31 7.154419 45.87004
23 32 7.156099 45.86983
```

Comment: Can you present what you tried ? Also supply reproducible example - this might be helpful if you are using google map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095495/ploting-coordinates-of-multiple-points-at-google-map-in-r

Comment: I have changed the lat o lon to spatial data and tried plot: > coordinates(data)= ~lon+lat and moreover, > plot(data$lon,data$lan,type="p", pch=22, lty=2, col="brown",xlab = "Lon" , ylab= "Lat" )

> plot(data)

Comment: If you want to use ggplot2, you cannot use the spatial data classes provided by the `sp` package, it only works on `data.frame`'s. To convert from spatial classes to data.frame, simply use `as.data.frame`, or don't convert them to spatial classes in the first place.

Comment: Strangely familiar data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095495/ploting-coordinates-of-multiple-points-at-google-map-in-r

Comment: @MattBagg, Mr. Amidi intrduce me the site, Is there any problem with using a same dataset for you?

Comment: Not really, but you might learn more by asking for help with why you get specific error messages in intermediate steps rather than asking for how to do final solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this use the [`geom_text`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_text.html) geometry:

```
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = df) + geom_text(aes(label = id))
```

This plots the text in the `id` column on the locations specfied by the columns `lon` and `lat`. The data is stored in the `data.frame` `df`.

or use:

```
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = df) + geom_text(aes(label = id)) + 
    geom_point()
```

if you want to add both a point and a label. Use the `hjust` and `vjust` parameters of `geom_text` to change the orientation of the label relative to the point. In addition, give each point a color according to the column `var` by using the `color` parameter in the `geom_point` aesthetics:

```
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = df) + geom_text(aes(label = id)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = var))
```

Do note that `ggplot2` cannot deal with the `Spatial` classes provided by the `sp` package. Use `as.data.frame` to convert point (SpatialPoints) and gridsets (SpatialPixels/SpatialGrid) to data.frame's. In addition, use `fortify` to convert polygon datasets (SpatialPolygons) to `data.frame`.

Comment: Is it possible to give each point a color and add them to legend?

Comment: ...added as an edit to the question. However, I recommend you read up on ggplot2 as these kinds of things can be found in the documentation of ggplot2.

Comment: I am reading it. I tried transparency for septate visualization of text and symbol by ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = data) + geom_text(aes(label = id)) + 
     geom_point(shape=23,alpha=3/4,size = 3, colour="gray",cex=.3) . But it doesn't give proper result. How can I change the position of the symbol, to the above or bottom?

Comment: For last update, I came up with this error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(colour = function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use)  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 23

Comment: Please add a reproducible example to your qeustion above.